# OzekiSDK not working on Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ozeki

Here is the error that I get when I add OzekiSDK to my project references:

```
Error 1 Exception while loading assemblies: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms.dll'
at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() SIPPHONE2
```

What is causing this error and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms` is not available on Xamarin.Android, therefore it is not possible to use this SDK as it appears to be targeted for Windows desktop apps.

Comment: can you sugest me  any voip ?

Comment: You could use something like Twilio: https://components.xamarin.com/view/twilio-client

Or PortSip: http://www.portsip.com/portsip-voip-sdk